# How to append string to uppercase letters in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, macos

Here's some sample code:

```
{"key_code":"a"},
{"key_code":"B"},
{"key_code":"c"},
{"key_code":"D"}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
{"key_code":"a"},
{"key_code":"b","modifiers":"left_shift"},
{"key_code":"c"},
{"key_code":"d","modifiers":"left_shift"}
```

In my IDE, I can do a case-sensitive search for `"([A-Z])"` and replace with `"\L$1", "modifiers": "left_shift"`, but I can't seem to get that to work in my bash script.

I'm on Mac OS X, so which is why I think `\L` is giving me troubles.

I've tried several versions of:

```
sed -i "" 's/"([A-Z])"/"\L$1","modifiers": "left_shift"/g' file
```

and

```
sed -i "" "s/\"([A-Z])\"/\"\L$1\",\"modifiers\": \"left_shift\"/g" file
```

But no luck. Trying to stumble through `awk`, but I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: Could you show a more complete JSON document? This would be easy to fix with `jq`.

Comment: You got answers to this question - please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

FreeBSD's `sed`, as found on macos, doesn't support `\L` in the replacement AFAIK. You can always use `perl` instead:

```bash
perl -pi -e 's/"\p{Lu}"/\L$&,"modifiers":"left_shift"/g' file
```

Add the `-C` option to also handle UTF-8 encoded non-ASCII uppercase letters (such as `Ê`, `Ç`, `Ξ`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the JSON objects that you show are part of a top-level array, like so (note that whitespace-characters outside of keys and values are irrelevant):

```json
[
  {
    "key_code": "a"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "B"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "c"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "D"
  }
]
```

Then we may test each `key_code` value for whether it's upper-case, and if it is, add the `modifiers` to that object:

```bsh
jq '(.[] | select(.key_code | test("[[:upper:]]"))) += { "modifiers": "left_shift" }' file
```

or, alternatively (but ever so slightly shorter),

```bsh
jq '(.[] | select(.key_code | test("[[:upper:]]"))).modifiers |= "left_shift"' file
```

or, using `map()` on the top-most array,

```bsh
jq 'map(select(.key_code | test("[[:upper:]]")).modifiers |= "left_shift")' file
```

With the given input in the question, this would produce the following output:

```json
[
  {
    "key_code": "a"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "B",
    "modifiers": "left_shift"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "c"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "D",
    "modifiers": "left_shift"
  }
]
```

If the array is kept elsewhere in a larger JSON document, you only need to change the initial `.[]` in the `jq` expression so that it extracts the relevant elements (the last example expression, with `map()`, obviously needs other changes).

Answer (score 0):

If the input looks exactly like that every time, this should suffice:

```bsh
awk '{if(/:"[A-Z]"/) sub(/"}/, "\",\"modifiers\":\"left_shift\"}"); print tolower($0) }' inputfile > outputfile
```

---

Another option could be this:

```bsh
sed 's/"[A-Z]"/&,"modifiers": "left_shift"/g' inputfile | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' > outputfile
```

Can't test on mac, but seems general enough that it should work.

Both the `tolower($0)` and the `tr` command will return everything in lowercase, which may or may not be desirable, so not a very flexible option.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed (install it on your Mac if you don't have it already):

```
$ sed 's/"[A-Z]"/\L&,"modifiers":"left_shift"/' file
{"key_code":"a"},
{"key_code":"b","modifiers":"left_shift"},
{"key_code":"c"},
{"key_code":"d","modifiers":"left_shift"}
```

Your existing code would also work in GNU sed if you used `\1` instead of `$1` for the backreference and escaped the parens to make them capture group boundaries instead of literal, e.g.:

```
$ sed 's/"\([A-Z]\)"/"\L\1","modifiers": "left_shift"/g' file
{"key_code":"a"},
{"key_code":"b","modifiers": "left_shift"},
{"key_code":"c"},
{"key_code":"d","modifiers": "left_shift"}
```

or enabled EREs instead of the default BREs:

```
$ sed -E 's/"([A-Z])"/"\L\1","modifiers": "left_shift"/g' file
{"key_code":"a"},
{"key_code":"b","modifiers": "left_shift"},
{"key_code":"c"},
{"key_code":"d","modifiers": "left_shift"}
```

Comment: `\L` doesn't work for me with FreeBSD `sed`. There's also no reference to it in [the man page for the latest version](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In that case I guess the OP would have to install GNU sed on their mac. Thanks for mentioning it, I updated my answer.

Comment: In standard `sed`, you can always use `y/ABC.../abc.../` and work with the hold place. But macos should have perl and awk, so there's little point going all that trouble.